# Callback in c++ - Could not understand

Tags: c++

I tried to understand how call back works...In the below program passing the `(void*)&obj` and receiving it in `(void* pt2Object)` is confusing me... `*pt2Object` will hold the value and not the address of some variable but here the reference is paased to it..
I could not understand how the `ClassA::Wrapper_To_Call_Display` func is passed and get accepted in `void (*pt2Function)(void* pt2Object,char* text))`...
Please help me to understand about it..

```
//---Program To use Function Pointers As A CallBack---

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ClassA
{
public:
  void Display(const char* text)
  {
    cout<<text<<endl;
  }
  static void Wrapper_To_Call_Display(void *pt2Object,char* text);
};
void ClassA::Wrapper_To_Call_Display(void *pt2Object,char* text)
{
  ClassA* myself = (ClassA*)pt2Object;
  myself->Display("string");
  cout<<text<<endl;
}
void DoIt(void* pt2Object, void(*pt2Function)(void* pt2Object, char* text)) {
  pt2Function(pt2Object, "Hi I am Calling back using an argument!!");
}
void Callback_Using_Argument() {
  ClassA obj;
DoIt((void*)&obj,ClassA::Wrapper_To_Call_Display);
}
int main() {
  Callback_Using_Argument();
  return 0;
}
```

### output

```
string
Hi I am Calling back using an argument!!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DoIt((void*)&obj,ClassA::Wrapper_To_Call_Display);
```

The `&obj` is not a reference. `&` returns the address of the `obj` which is an instance of the `ClassA` class.
The next parameter (`ClassA::Wrapper_To_Call_Display`) is the address of the function (note that it comes without the `()` that are required for a function call).

> *pt2Object will hold the value and not the address of some variable

`*pt2Object` is a variable which holds a value. The value is an address of some other variable (that's a pointer).

The whole `void*` and casting is a mess and that's not the way it should be done in C++, use casting operators instead.